# How to use an arrow function to return an array with all its even elements incremented by 1, and odd elements decremented by 1?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

> **Task**
>
> You are given a variable, my_function. Your task is to assign it with
>   an arrow function.  The my_function should take an array as its
>   parameter and return an array with all its even elements incremented
>   by 1, and odd elements decremented by 1.
>
> **Note**
>
> - **DON'T** use function instead of an arrow function.
> - **DON'T** print anything on the console.
> - Replace the blank (_________) with an arrow function.
> - The name of the array parameter can be anything. For example, some_array.

My current code is below, but the Current Buffer told me there is SyntaxError: Unexpected token if.

```
// write the correct arrow function here
var my_function = some_array => some_array.map((currentValue, index) => if(index % 2 === 0) currentValue + 1; else currentValue - 1;);
```

Comment: The concise body form of the arrow function has to return an expression; `if` is a statement, not an expression, so you'll need to use `{` and also `return`. Or you could use the ternary operator.

Comment: The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) shows the syntax and examples. When you run into a problem, read the documentation first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var my_function = some_array => some_array.map(
    (currentValue, index) => currentValue + (currentValue % 2 ? -1 : 1)
);
```

Note that you had a spelling mistake in `currentValue` and that you should not use `if` but the ternary operator.

Also, you can save a comparison with zero (`== 0`), by swapping the condition and sub-expressions that follow it. And finally, I moved `currentValue` out of the conditional part, since it has to be used for both cases.

Comment: Thanks, it works! It's actually asking the even and odd currentValue, not the index. I corrected your code as follows: var my_function = some_array => some_array.map(currentValue => currentValue + (currentValue % 2 ? -1 : 1));

Comment: Ah, I see. I made the same correction in my answer.